# How can relate "block of memory" to "objects" in Java?

Tags: java, memory, memory-leaks

How can I define an object in Java in a way that would mean 'block of memory'?

Answer (score 4):

Here are couple of examples:

```
final byte[] blockOfMemory = new byte[ 1024 ];

final java.nio.ByteBuffer blockOfMemory2 =
    java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocateDirect( 1024 );
```

Comment: a) The JVM Specification http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/VMSpecTOC.doc.html

b) The API-doc http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html